# SOLR4/lucene and JVM memory management

Tags: solr, lucene, jvm, solr4

Does anyone know how solr4/lucene and the JVM, manages memory?

We have the following case.

We have a 15GB server running only SOLR4/Lucene and the JVM (no custom code)

We had allocated 2GB of memory and the JVM was using 1.9MB. At some point something happened and we run out of memory.

Then we increased the JVM memory to 4GB and we see that gradually, JVM starts to use as much as it can. It is now using 3GB out of the 4GB allocated.

Is that normal JVM memory usage? i.e. Does the JVM always use as much as it can from the allocated space?

Thanks for your help

Comment: There are several reasons which may drive SOLR to OOM.
Do you use facets? What other caches have you enabled? What is the Directory implementation you are using? Standard?MMap?NIO?

Comment: Hi @lexk, We do use facets. Caches enabled in our solrconfig.xml are filterCache. fieldValueCache and DocumentCache. We do NOT ahve queryResultCache enabled. Our filterCache size is 16384, our documentCache is 2048 and fieldValueCache is 4096. We do not have a Directory implementation directive in solrconfig.xml so I guess we use the Standard implementation. Total documents indexed are 8M documents with a size close to 20GB. Hope this helps you in providing some insights.

Answer (score 0):

Facets are using field cache. If you have a lot of fields (even small) which are used for faceting, it very well may be that eventually you hit your memory limit.

if you have a lot of query facets or define a lot of FQ - in your case 1Mb is allocated per each filter cache entry. You have defined 16384 as an upper bound, so you may also hit large numbers there eventually.

Hope this helps.